# Select time value or date value from datetime with C# odbc

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I have a SQL query being sent by C# `system.data.odbc OdbcCommand` object.

```
SELECT Calldate 
  FROM calls;
```

The `Calldate` column is a datetime type.

I want the select statement to only return the date portion of the value. The DateValue function doesn't seem to do anything.  I am hoping to achieve this within the SQL provided to the OdbcCommand object.

Edit 1: The resource being queried is an access mdb file.

Comment: There's a couple of formats you could [CAST/CONVERT the value to that don't include the time portion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)...

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, Calldate, 103) FROM Calls; -- This replies undefined function. SELECT CAST(Calldate AS varchar) FROM Calls; --This replies syntax error.

Comment: You have an option of getting date or time part in c# when data is retrieved from the db. In many cases performance can be comparable.

Comment: Yeah, I know :L The problem is that for a number of reasons it will be messy and inellegent. I am hoping to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using sql server, you can convert the datetime

```
select convert(datetime, CallDate, x) from calls
```

x can represent different notations/numeric values for different date formatting. See this link for all the different numeric values, and the examples of their output.

http://linesofcode.net/snippets/45

EDIT (based on the fact that OP is using access, not SQL server)

You can format any string using the MS format function:

```
SELECT Format(CallDate,'yyyy/mm/dd') FROM calls
```

more formatting options here: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/SQL/access_functions/format.php

Comment: and if it queries an access mdb file by odbc?

Comment: you are assuming that we are working with MS SQL Server database. We are not. CAST and CONVERT do not work in MS Access.

Comment: When he wrote that I had not provided that information. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about -

`select datevalue(Calldate) from calls;`

Other functions listed [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/)

Comment: Sorry, as stated in the question. That function doesn't work.