# Changing dataset data for datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to update an attribute inside a dataset, which is then displayed in a datagrid. However, when I attempt to assign the date to my row.ItemArray[0] it doesn't appear to be updating. Not in debug nor in the datagrid.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        string date = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        date = date.Remove(date.Length - 12);
        row.ItemArray[0] = date;

        foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            // read item
            //Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
ds.AcceptChanges();
invoicesDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
invoicesDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: you can't do it that way.. you need to assign the actual row[0][0] = date

Comment: @MethodMan : Hope that is is not possible to change the collection while iteration.

Comment: actually it is possible I just did it and it worked..I will post my answer in a minute I need to head to a meeting real quick

Comment: Please put your query here..You may change  this in your query so no need this code any more

Answer (score 1):

make your select query like below

```
select cast(yourdatecolumnName as date) As date from yourtableName
```

Comment: I think you want to remove time from date time.above query is use full for this

Comment: I have to run this through odbc. The cast isn't giving me only date.
`
"SELECT cast(Sales.InvoiceDate as date) AS date , Sales.OutstandingBalance, Sales.InvoiceStatusID, Cards.Name "
                                + "FROM Sales INNER JOIN Cards ON Sales.CardRecordID = Cards.CardRecordID "
                                + "WHERE Sales.InvoiceStatusID='O' AND Sales.InvoiceDate >= '" + startDate + "' AND Sales.InvoiceDate <= '" + endDate + "' "
                                + "ORDER BY Sales.InvoiceDate DESC;" `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865066/select-time-value-or-date-value-from-datetime-with-c-sharp-odbc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922538/howto-convert-datetime-to-date-with-an-odbc-function

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following below. you do not need that many nested foreach loops

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++) 
    {
       string date = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
       date = date.Remove(date.Length - 12);
       string val = row[i].ToString();
       row[i] = date;
       Debug.WriteLine("oldValue: {0}, newValue: {1}", val, row[i].ToString());
    }
}
invoicesDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
invoicesDataGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Comment: This is almost the same as what I've tried previously with less loops. The only issue with this code is the for loop. Since its already in the row, I only need to modify the row[0] always, per row. Despite that, this still isn't working. Still no update, when I see it in the datagrid.

Comment: Is it possible for datasets to have datatypes for column. row[0] for example comes out from a database as a dateTime I think. So, would that mean I can't put a string into that column?